# How to use Python3 map correctly?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, shuffle

For some data like:

```
foo = list()
foo.append( ["a", "b", "c"] )
foo.append( ["d", "e", "f"] )
foo.append( ["g", "h", "i"] )
```

I could use `map(shuffle, foo)` in **Python 2** to shuffle each sublist of foo and get back a list from map.

In **Python 3** map (as many other methods) return an object, in this case a map object containing some iterator with the values (at least this is what I thought).

So I tried a list comprehension:

```
[ element for element in map(shuffle, foo) ]
```

And the list constructor:

```
list( map(shuffle, foo) )
```

As well as a simple for loop:

```
for element in map(shuffle, foo)
```

**But what I always get is this stuff**:

```
[None, None, None]
```

I do not understand why? Can someone lighten this up for me?

In addition to this, another strange thing:

```
# simply calling map
map( shuffle, foo ) # <-- does nothing, foo's elements remain in the same order

# saving the output
someThing = map( shuffle, foo ) # <-- foo's elements are shuffled
```

Why does the first thing do not shuffle foo's elements but the second does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffle will shuffle the elements in-place, which means the function will return `None`.

In both your list constructor and comprehension examples, the list that you create is a list of the `None`s that were returned from your shuffle function calls. If you were to iterate over `foo` again, they should be shuffled.

In your second to final example where you said that `map()` "does nothing" and that the elements remain in the same order, that's only because execution of the shuffle function has been deferred until you try to iterate over the return value of your call to map:

```
new_iterator = map(shuffle, foo)
for element in new_iterator:
    pass
```

In this snippet, each element will be `None` like you observed. But the act of iterating over the generator that map will returned will cause the shuffle function to actually be executed, and if you look at foo again, it should now be shuffled.

Last note: the snippet I wrote above is a stupid way to do what you're trying to do. To still accomplish what you want in one line, you can do a list comprehension, and just throw away the list of `Nones`:

```
[shuffle(element) for element in foo]
```

Don't assign the resulting list to anything. If you look at `foo` again, the sublists should be shuffled.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I shuffle the list foo somehow and not end up with several lines of code or a new method my_shuffle like in rightfolds answer?

Comment: @ascenator See edit. Use the list comprehension shown without assigning the resulting list to anything.

Answer (score 2):

`shuffle` shuffles the list *in-place* and by the command-query separation principle returns `None` instead of the list. You can wrap it like this:

```
def my_shuffle(xs):
    xs = list(xs)
    shuffle(xs)
    return xs
```

This will leave the input list untouched and return a new list which is shuffled.